# create a dubs duplication item in a list comprehension in python

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I want to create a duplication item in a list comprehension in python

In Python you can have multiple iterators in a list comprehension, like

```
[(x,y) for x in a for y in b]
```

for some suitable sequences a and b. I'm aware of the loop semantics of Python's list comprehensions.

My question is: Can an iterator in the comprehension refer to the other? In other words: Could I have something like this:

```
arr = [1,2,3,4]
dubs = []
dubs = [[x] + [arr[arr.index(x)]] for x in ]
dubs = [x for l in dubs for x in l]
```

As an example, if I have a simple list:

```
arr = [1,2,3,4]
```

what would the list comprehension expression be to achieve this result:

```
dubs = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]
```

Please only list comprehension answers.

Comment: `[i for i in arr for _ in range(2)]` ?

Comment: Your wording is very confusing here. `[1,2,3,4]` is not a nested list, it's just a flat list of ints.

Comment: A nice (or not) hack `list((yield i) or i for i in arr)`

Comment: What is the point of `[x] + [arr[arr.index(x)]] `??? just do `[x, x]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change your existing code to make it work by first building a nested list and then flattening it:

```
dubs = [[x]+[x] for x in arr]
dubs = [x for l in dubs for x in l]
```

In other words, the thing you need to loop over (what you seemed to be stuck on) is just the element of `arr`, and the thing you need to add to each element singleton `[x]` is just another copy of `[x]`. With your `[arr[arr.index(x)]]`, you're trying to look up `x` in the array just so you can get back the value of whatever you find—which is just going to be `x` if it works, so just use `x`.

---

You can make this slightly better:

```
dubs = [[x]*2 for x in arr]
dubs = [x for l in dubs for x in l]
```

Or, of course:

```
dubs = [[x,x] for x in arr]
dubs = [x for l in dubs for x in l]
```

---

But it's probably simpler, even if less concise, to do this:

```
dubs = [[x for _ in range(2)] for x in arr]
dubs = [x for l in dubs for x in l]
```

And then, as jpp pointed out in a comment, you can then simplify that to:

```
dubs = [x for x in arr for _ in range(2)]
```

---

Or, alternatively, notice that all of the above are giving us the same things as `[list(z) for z in zip(arr, arr)]`. And if we're just flattening the zip, we don't need to convert it to a list of lists instead of an iterator of tuples, just use it as-is:

```
dubs = zip(arr, arr)
dubs = [x for l in dubs for x in l]
```

… which you can again simplify:

```
[x for l in zip(arr, arr) for x in l]
```

Comment: [[x]*2 for x in arr] will  give nested list ,,

Comment: @Roushan Yes, if you want to make it work by building a nested list and flattening it, you obviously need to build a nested list.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that you want the index and the item rather than the item twice.  In that case you will want to use `enumerate()`.  The second parameter of `enumerate()` specifies the starting index to use when returning the (index, value) tuples.  To start at `0` omit the `start` parameter.

```
dubs = [(i, v) for i, v in enumerate(arr,1)]
```

This will give a list of tuples which can be flattened as [@abarnert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50080051/4637583) showed

```
dubs = [x for l in dubs for x in l]
```

Comment: Why you do think he wants the indexes? The question wording isn’t all that clear, but his attempted solution doesn’t use the index, it uses `arr[the index]`, which I assume he must have had some reason for doing. (Also, the name `dubs` suggests that he wants doubles.)

Comment: @abarnert I agree that the wording is not clear.  There is room for interpretation on the desired output.  Your answer covers the `[x]*2` option nicely.  I thought I would put this option out there in case  OP (or someone searching in the future) wants the indexes.

Answer (score -2):

loop the same element twice then it will result to duplicate

```
In [6]: [i for i in arr for h in range(2)]
Out[6]: [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]
```

Simple one without list comprehension **if you have sorted list**

```
In [7]: sorted(arr*2)
Out[7]: [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]
```

Comment: the `sorted` one assumes that you want the result in sorted order, which is not clear and I would assume it is not the case

Comment: `sorted` won't do the right thing unless you can assume the input will always be exactly the same as the example (in which case you could just hardcode `[1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4]` and be done with it, so there's no point doing anything more complicated).